# Driver for 3.5 inch touch Screen (GPIO) which supports KALI LINUX

Tags: screen, kali

I have recently bought a 3.5 inch touchscreen for my Raspberry Pi 2 B+. After a lot of search I got this driver (working).

But it is only supports Raspbian. I want to run it on KALI. Please Help.

Comment: bit late, but for anyone else looking for it..... https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show